# Search for files in a directory find them and email them

Tags: c#

In a part of my program the application should search for certain files in installation directory and, if found, should email those files. So far I have:

```
try
{
  MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
  string[] file1 = Directory.GetFiles("some directories", "some files");
  string[] file2 = Directory.GetFiles("some directories", "some files");
  string[] file3 = Directory.GetFiles("some directories", "some files");

  foreach (var file in file1)
  {
    Attachment someFiles = new Attachment(file);
    mail.Attachments.Add(someFiles);
  }

  foreach (var file in file2)
  {
    Attachment someFiles1 = new Attachment(file);
    mail.Attachments.Add(someFiles1);
  }

  foreach (var file in file3)
  {
    Attachment someFiles2 = new Attachment(file);
    mail.Attachments.Add(someFiles2);
  }


  SmtpClient server = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
  mail.From = new MailAddress("someone@gmail.com");
  mail.To.Add("someone@gmail.com");
  mail.Subject = "subject";
  server.Port = 587;
  server.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("someone@gmail.com", "password");
  server.EnableSsl = true;
  server.Send(mail);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string stat = ex.ToString();
    MessageBox. Show(stat);
}
```

There is no exception but no email is sent. Where is the problem?

Comment: Is the email being treated as spam? Thus thrown away without diagnostic. Try sending a simple email with a better subject and simple text content to ensure you have communication.

Comment: @p19lord, Sometimes it takes more than an hour to see the sent mail. If you open the mail via `outlook` instead of `gmail`, it may help.

Comment: Use some network inspector like wireshark, to check the program really does not send the mails. Maybe just your SMTP configuration is bad.

Comment: try sending the email without the attachments.
Your code seems fine.
Maybe you have a problem with the size of the files.

Comment: Most SMTP servers have a low limit on the size of outgoing mail. I believe that Gmail's maximum is currently 25 MB (which translates to around 18 MB before MIME encoding).

Comment: @Richard I did it server is fine it is sending simple mails and there is nothing in spams!

Comment: @user3165438 It should be sent by bcoz I am tryin it from last night!

Comment: @GeorgeVovos Withou attachments it works but the whole point of this email sending is those attachments and attachments size collected aren't more than 2MB

Comment: What are the types of the files you are trying to send?

Comment: Also try setting the Timeout property to 0 (server.Timeout = 0;)
I think the default is 100 seconds.
Though,if that was the problem you would get a TimeOutException

Comment: @GeorgeVovos Still no luck. The file type is sqlt

Comment: I'm afraid i cannot think anything else.
One last thing.
Add this line after the  "server.Send(mail);"
 MessageBox. Show("Success");
Do you see the message "Success"?
Also,try running your code without debbugging (ctrl+ F5 in visual studio)

Comment: @GeorgeVovos I know It is irrelevant but weirdly when I add the MessageBox it worked!!